# Handling Exception in HttpClient Ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform

I have written a common code in a common module as below and tested in JS environment

```
val response = client.post<HttpResponse>(url) {
    body = TextContent("""{"a":1,"b":2}""", ContentType.Application.Json)
}
if (response.status != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    logger.error("Error, this one failed bad?")
}
```

But my code ends at client.post with a canceled corutineException on no network. How do I handle this and any other exception? If there is an internet connection. Nothing fails, I want to be able to handle the exceptions. How?

Note: try, catch doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well after asking here and there, I got help from [github issues](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/949) and came to this work arround

```
try {
    val response = client.post<HttpResponse>(url) {
        body = TextContent("""{"a":1,"b":2}""", ContentType.Application.Json)
    }
    if (response.status != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        logger.error("Error, this one failed bad?")
    }
} catch (cause: Throwable) {
    logger.error("Catch your error here")
}
```

don't confuse to `catch (c: Throwable)` with `catch (e: Exception)`

hope this helps

Comment: What is the idiomatic way to wrap this try-catch block? Maybe some kind of inline function?

Comment: How do you differentiate between a network failure (which you can display to the user but otherwise ignore) vs. errors indicating something is broken (such as deserialization errors when using `KotlinxSerializer` for responses) and should be sent to crash reporting tool?

Answer (score 15):

We can handle it in a central way using this extension function that wraps Success and error cases. We can have Network Error, Serialisation Error or Server Errors which may expose error bodies/messages for the UI and http status code.

```
suspend inline fun <reified T, reified E> HttpClient.safeRequest(
    block: HttpRequestBuilder.() -> Unit,
): ApiResponse<T, E> =
    try {
        val response = request { block() }
        ApiResponse.Success(response.body())
    } catch (e: ClientRequestException) {
        ApiResponse.Error.HttpError(e.response.status.value, e.errorBody())
    } catch (e: ServerResponseException) {
        ApiResponse.Error.HttpError(e.response.status.value, e.errorBody())
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        ApiResponse.Error.NetworkError
    } catch (e: SerializationException) {
        ApiResponse.Error.SerializationError
    }

suspend inline fun <reified E> ResponseException.errorBody(): E? =
    try {
        response.body()
    } catch (e: SerializationException) {
        null
    }
```

Here's the `ApiResponse` defined below so there's working code:

```
sealed class ApiResponse<out T, out E> {
    /**
     * Represents successful network responses (2xx).
     */
    data class Success<T>(val body: T) : ApiResponse<T, Nothing>()

    sealed class Error<E> : ApiResponse<Nothing, E>() {
        /**
         * Represents server (50x) and client (40x) errors.
         */
        data class HttpError<E>(val code: Int, val errorBody: E?) : Error<E>()

        /**
         * Represent IOExceptions and connectivity issues.
         */
        object NetworkError : Error<Nothing>()

        /**
         * Represent SerializationExceptions.
         */
        object SerializationError : Error<Nothing>()
    }
}
```

I found `ApiResponse` works well for my case but you don't necessarily have to model your api responses as this if you have other/special cases, you can also use [kotlin-result](https://github.com/michaelbull/kotlin-result) or [Arrow's Either](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core/arrow.core/-either/index.html).

Comment: I really like this solution but I'm getting an error on the following line:
`val response = request { block() }`

Not enough information to infer type variable T

Comment: @Rahul Sainani is correct!
This is the correct way!!
[Ktor Response validation](https://ktor.io/docs/response-validation.html)

Answer (score 9):

Not adding much to the current answer but in response to CVS's comment I've been using the following to add ktor client error handling in my applications. It makes use of the [Result](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/) API. `runCatching {}` catches all `Throwable`s and you can tweak the behaviour of the `getOrElse` block to capture the exceptions you're interested in.

```
suspend fun <T> HttpClient.requestAndCatch(
    block: suspend HttpClient.() -> T,
    errorHandler: suspend ResponseException.() -> T
): T = runCatching { block() }
    .getOrElse {
        when (it) {
            is ResponseException -> it.errorHandler()
            else -> throw it
        }
    }

// Example call
client.requestAndCatch(
    { get<String>("/") },
    {
        when (response.status) {
            HttpStatusCode.BadRequest -> {} // Throw errors or transform to T 
            HttpStatusCode.Conflict -> {}
            else -> throw this
        }
    }
)
```

I'm sure it could be made tidier but it's the best I've come up with so far.

Comment: This is a terrible idea to use suspending functions and runCatching at the same time. It will leak your coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who doesn't want to use try catch

```
override suspend fun requestGPT(model: RequestModel, result: (response: ResponseModel?, error: String?) -> Unit) {
    val httpResponse = client.post {
        headerGpt()
        header("Content-Type","application/json")
        setBody(model)
        url(Endpoints.requestGpt)
    }
    if (httpResponse.status.value in 200..299) {
        result(httpResponse.body<ResponseModel>(),null)
    }else{
        result(null,"Error Http Status Code --> ${httpResponse.status.value} \n ${httpResponse.bodyAsText()}")
    }
}
```

Usage will be like

```
 repository.requestGPT(model){response, error ->
    response?.let {
        println("$response")
    }
    error?.let {
        println("$error")
    }
  }
```